# Modal verb + "be able to"

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs, redundancy

> I might (be able to) help you.
>
> You may (be able to) get extra money.
>
> You should (be able to) feel this
>
> You re foolish to expect to (be able to) do that.

Is there any meaningful difference between the versions with and without *be able to* ?

Comment: "*I might help*" is about the future possibly of me helping you. It's not clear what the conditions are for my helping you. "*I might be able to help*" literally is about my possible future ability to help you, but really it implies, "*If I'm able to help you, I will, but I'm unsure I will be able to.*"

Answer (score 2):

For the first one there is a definite difference. *I might help you* sounds very grudging (I might if I feel like it), while *I might be able to help you* suggests 'I will help you if it is at all possible'.

In the other sentences, again *be able to* carries an implication of the possibility or capability existing.

Comment: "I might help you..."  also might sound in some contexts to be quietly asking "...and what will you do for me in return?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference.

If you omit the adjective '*able*', the statement is no longer about *ability*.

Taking your first example:

- I might help you

This gives no reason or detail about why you might, or might not give help. It might be entirely down to your random whim, and you are choosing whether to help or not.

- I might be able to help you.

This means that the help depends on your *ability*, or other circumstances that might contribute to that ability. It implies that if you *can* help them, you *will*.

Comment: You might clarify between the various "you" here by saying "speaker" and "listener".   Your last sentence might be seen to mean something you don't intend.